# Can you populate a pre-populated drop down list in asp C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

As of right now, I have a ddl that I already have populated with the information from a table. It is a list of customers that is set to auto-postback. The problem I am running into, is the fact the default selection is always the first customer on the list and when you click on one customer in does the post back and gets all the information needed and also sets the selection to the first customer and does not do the post back.

So a fix that I have thought of and have been trying to achieve is putting a null value in the ddl that is something like "Please Select Customer".. 
I have gone into the DDLs edit items and added this, but the call to the table that it does not include it. Is there a way for it to be included.

With Mozilla Firefox, I do not run into this problem, because after the postback it stays on the same customer. If I can clear anything up, I will do my best, if there is any piece of code that could be useful, I can provide it

```
//save the value of the current selection to reselect later if still exists
string origSelectedItem = ddlSelectedCustomer.SelectedValue;

//clear and refill the list
ddlSelectedCustomer.Items.Clear();

//check what role the user is in
string usersRole = Roles.GetRolesForUser(Membership.GetUser().UserName)[0];

MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();

switch (usersRole)
{
    case "SalesRep":
         ddlSelectedCustomer.DataSource = 
         DAL.Util.getSalesRepCustomers((Guid)user.ProviderUserKey);
         ddlSelectedCustomer.DataBind();
         break;

    case "BasicUser":
    case "Customer":
         ddlSelectedCustomer.DataSource = 
         DAL.Util.getCustomersListForUser((Guid)user.ProviderUserKey);
         ddlSelectedCustomer.DataBind();
         break;

    case "Admin":
    case "SuperAdmin":
         ddlSelectedCustomer.DataSource = DAL.Util.getAllCustomersList(); 
         ddlSelectedCustomer.DataBind();
         break;
    default:
         break;
}

//if user had a company selected, reselect it if it exists
if (origSelectedItem != string.Empty)
    ddlSelectedCustomer.SelectedValue = origSelectedItem;
else if (ddlSelectedCustomer.Items.Count == 1)    
    //if only one item in the list, select it
    ddlSelectedCustomer.Items[0].Selected = true;
```

Also this is in the code-behind on the master page of the site.

Thank you

Comment: Code snippet of how you set the DDL datasource?

Comment: Code would be helpful. At first glance I suspect you're re-populating your DDL on each page refresh instead of just the first visit. That would cause the DDL to 'forget' what you selected. Not sure about the FF behavior though...

Comment: This sounds like a riddle - like 'Who is buried in Grant's tomb?'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `AppendDataBoundItems` to true, and then you can add an empty first item.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" /> <!-- empty first item -->    
</asp:DropDownList>
```

It's important to note that if you bind the list more than once, you will need to clear the list so it doesn't append duplicate items.

If you want to add the empty item in code-behind, after you clear the list out, you can do it like this:

```
DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(string.Empty, string.Empty));

//bind list
```

Comment: Was looking for something like this. I was suspecting it would be along the lines of this, but it did not resolve it in this instance.

Comment: That's because you're clearing the list before you bind it. If you want, you can add the empty item in code-behind, after clearing the contents of the list.

Comment: Ahh blinded by the obvious thank you Very much James that solves my problem!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has already but also an alternate to add it to just the codebehind without touching the aspx would be: with your variables:

```
ddlSelectedCustomer.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select"));
```

this would add "Please Select" as your very first item in your ddl